Hello ! I am getting an error message in my formula one that says "unexpected Characters and invalid number of arguments
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2('Send to email'.Text,Subject.Text,Substitute(Body.Text,Char(13),""),{Cc:ManagerEmail.Text & ";" & 'User Email'.Text},
Select(ResetButton),
Notify("Thank you. Email has been sent!",NotificationType.Success,5000)
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2('Send to email'.Text,Subject.Text,Substitute(Body.Text,Char(13),""),{Cc:ManagerEmail.Text & ";" & 'User Email'.Text},
Select(ResetButton),
Notify("Thank you. Email has been sent!",NotificationType.Success,5000)
This is what I tried but I keep getting an error

It looks like you included the select and notify functions within the SendEmailv2 function. This way it thinks these are arguments of the SendEmailv2 function. Can you place them outside of the function and try again.
Try something like:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    'Send to email'.Text,
    Subject.Text,
    Body.Text,
    {
        Cc: ManagerEmail.Text,
        Bcc: 'User Email'.Text
    }
);
Notify("Thank you. Email has been sent!",NotificationType.Success,5000)


You are missing a closing bracket and few functions are misplaced in your formula.
Try using formula like below:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    'Send to email'.Text,
    Subject.Text,
    Substitute(Body.Text,Char(13),""),
    {Cc:ManagerEmail.Text & ";" & 'User Email'.Text}
);
Select(ResetButton);
Notify("Thank you. Email has been sent!",NotificationType.Success,5000)

Documentation: Office 365 Outlook connector - Send an email (V2)
